# A typical way of expressing an improper integral.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{a}f(x)dx =a $

and also, $\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{a}g(x)dx =a $

Then, can I say simply $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)=  \int_0^{\infty}g(x)$ ?

I guess this is true but I am not sure because each improper integral is diverging. I am not confident that we can say equality of improper integral.

$\textbf{Additional question}$: Greg Martin commented that the above equation doesn't make sense and I agree.
I changed the question like this:
Assume $lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}(\int_0^a f(x)dx−∫_0^a g(x)dx)=0$, then, can I say $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int_0^{\infty}g(x)dx$?

Comment: These expressions don't make sense, on the left hand side $a$ exists only inside the limit (it is called a dummy variable, you could use any other symbol to replace it while retaining the same meaning), so it cannot be used on the right hand side.

Comment: I see. How about this setting. Assume $\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty}( \int_0^a f(x) dx - \int_0^a g(x) dx )=0$, then, now can I say  $ \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty} g(x) dx $?

Comment: If you want to change the question's phrasing, it's better to do that in the body of the question and not just in comments. But the answer to the new question is "no" because the individual limits need not exist (consider for example $f(x)=g(x)=\sin x$).

Comment: @martian03  You should be able to prove this.   *Assume $f,g:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ are continuous, that $\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_0^a [f(x)-g(x)]\,dx=0$ and that the improper integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ exists.  Then so too does the improper integral $\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx$ and the two integrals are equal.*